# Expected distance between (X, Y), where both X and Y are standrd normal random variabls and the origin

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, bivariate, chi-distribution

Let $(X, Y)$ be two independent standard random variable, with mean and SD being 0 and 1 respectively.

What would be $E[\sqrt(X^2 + Y^2)]$, the expected distance between $(X, Y)$ and the origin.

Comment: This reads like a textbook style question. Is this for some subject?

Comment: However, it's answered a few times on site already - sometimes in a more general form (e.g. see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272885/intuition-for-rayleigh-pdf/272932#272932))

Answer (score 2):

$Z=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ is a [Chi](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Chi_distribution) distributed random variable with degree of freedom $k=2$. Its mean is 
$$\mu=\sqrt{2}\frac{\Gamma((k+1)/2)}{\Gamma(k/2)}=\sqrt{2} \Gamma(3/2)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$